# Insert a page-break in a text file

Tags: c#, text-files

I am trying to insert a list in a text file which, according to a condition such as a customer change , a jump page.
But for now I can not find how to make the page break .
Can anyone help me?

```
table.Rows.Add("06"+ "SIRET : "+ resultatSiretFou);
table.Rows.Add("07"+ resultatIso+" "+ resultatCee);
table.Rows.Add("08"+ "FOURNISSEUR  : "+ resultatLibelleFou);
table.Rows.Add("09"+ "");
table.Rows.Add("11"+ resultatClasse);
table.Rows.Add("12"+ position10 + resultatClasse);
```

for example , make a page break between my line 8 and 9.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    string[] fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).ToArray();
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join("\t", fields));
}

File.WriteAllText(@"D:\bla\bla\bla.txt", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: text files dont have page breaks..

Comment: I read somewhere that \f might work.

Comment: I was just going to say `\f`.  Form feed.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break.  But of course, a text editor would never do anything with that because there is no notion of "pages" in a text editor.  Maybe if you opened it in a word processor...maybe.

Comment: Nope.  Tried it in MS Word -- didn't work.  Nevermind.

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Text files have no inherent notion of pages. You can put a line break (`Environment.NewLine`) or a run of empty lines, or a break of "__________________________", for example, but that's it.

Comment: @geteo - what do you want the page break to do?  How/where are you going to print this?  There does exist an ASCII code for Form Feed, but it's unlikely to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion uses Microsoft Word to get the result.

You can insert a '`especial code`' at the desired end of page in your text, for example '`\p`'. Then save as a Word 97 or posterior document.

Open the file with Microsoft Word and then go to Find and replace menu, and in Find what put the '`\p`', and in Replace with set '`^m`'. You can find this and other especial codes under special options.

I have tested this procedure saving text to word with python. I hope it will work with other languages.